# Query list of computers - output last logged on user and last logon date

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am creating a script to retrieve all the machine names from a .txt file then Query against them;

ComputerName
UserName (Of the last person to logon to the machine)
Date it was last Logged on to/Used

## This is what i have

```
Clear-Host
$machines = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Winver\MachineNames.txt
ForEach ($Compu in $machines) {
    Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $machines –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select 
    Username, PSComputerName | FT
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? Are you wanting to time of when the last person logged on? I don't think this information is stored anywhere

Comment: Your info starts telling what you're doing but whats the actual question? Besides that, are the computers part of a domain? If so, you can query the Domain with `Get-ADComputer`

Comment: You seem to keep asking the same question over and over again, and everytime you show the same code where you user the `Get-WmiObject` method. That however does **NOT** provide a last logon timestamp. My code does, but you need to be administrator on all machines you query in order to be allowed to parse the Security eventlog. You might also have a look at what PowerShell versions all machines you query have..

Comment: This field seems to be wrong, its giving me back my UserName for every machine i query instead of the user that last loggedon to it. " @{Name ='UserName';     Expression = {$_.Properties[1].Value}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sidenotes:

- the hyphens for the parameter names are not hyphens, but [En-Dash](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html)es, so I gather this code is copied from the internet somewhere
- inside the loop you are using the wrong variable on the ComputerName parameter which should be `$Compu`

Having said that, I don't think you can get the info you need from the WMI Win32_ComputerSystem class..
What you will need to do is to parse the info from the computers eventlog:

```
# get an array of computernames loaded from the text file
$machines = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Winver\MachineNames.txt

$result = foreach ($computer in $machines) {
    # test if the compurer is on-line
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' is off-line."
        # skip this computer and carry on with the next iteration
        continue
    }

    # search the computers eventlog and parse the username and last logon time from that
    # you can play around with other values for -MaxEvents if you feel you're missing information.
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 20 | 
        Where-Object { $_.Properties[1].Value -notmatch 'SYSTEM|NETWORK SERVICE|LOCAL SERVICE' } | 
        Select-Object @{Name ='ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.MachineName}},
                      @{Name ='UserName';     Expression = {$_.Properties[1].Value}},
                      @{Name ='LastLogon';    Expression = {$_.TimeCreated}} -First 1

}

# show on screen:
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\LastLogonInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Update**

If I understand your comment correctly, you would like a list of all users (except for a few) and retrieve their **latest** login on a computer from the list.

In that case you can do the following:

```
# get an array of computernames loaded from the text file
$machines = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Winver\MachineNames.txt
$result = foreach ($computer in $machines) {
    # test if the compurer is on-line
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$computer' is off-line."
        # skip this computer and carry on with the next iteration
        continue
    }

    # you do not want to include these account logins
    $exclude = '\$|SYSTEM|NETWORK SERVICE|LOCAL SERVICE|KHALIFAM'
    # search the computers eventlog and parse the username and last logon time from that
    # you can play around with other values for -MaxEvents if you feel you're missing information.
    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 100 | 
        Where-Object { $_.Properties[1].Value -notmatch $exclude } | 
        Select-Object @{Name ='ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.MachineName}},
                      @{Name ='UserName';     Expression = {$_.Properties[1].Value}},
                      @{Name ='LastLogon';    Expression = {$_.TimeCreated}} |
        Group-Object -Property UserName | ForEach-Object {
            $_.Group | Sort-Object LastLogon -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
        }
}

# show on screen:
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\LastLogonInfo.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Wow! You're a legend! Thanks... for some reason the results im getting arent exactly what i wanted, The Username is supposed to be the person to last logon not my Admin account lol



PSComputerName             UserName   LastLogon          
--------------             --------   ---------          
LN-M83-PC01C2YC.cooley.com KHALIFAM.a 10/10/2019 15:57:09

LN-T46-PC0FRQLN.cooley.com KHALIFAM.a 10/10/2019 15:58:20

LN-T48-PF127RTJ.cooley.com KHALIFAM.a 10/10/2019 15:58:44

Comment: @Khalifa96 You can add `|KHALIFAM` to the list of users you do not want to match. (Mind the or symbol `|`)

Comment: How do i learn to code like that if i may ask? i'm very impressed

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of user names of people who have logged on to the computers from a list of machines in a .txt file then export into a .csv table which displays

The ComputerName
The UserName (Of the last person to log on to it)
The Last time the user logged on to the machine

Comment: @Khalifa96 I have added more code to get a list of users that have logged in to each machine. Hope that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks again, i will try run that in a moment. What i really want is the output to display in the following format. I want the results to be in this formatt.

MachineName | Username | LogonDate

Comment: The script runs fine as it identifies the offline machine but i also get this error

Get-WinEvent : A security package specific error occurred
At line:15 char:5
+     Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $computer -FilterHashtable @{Logname=' ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEven 
   tCommand

Comment: Some machines seems to work but results dont look right.

ComputerName               UserName         LastLogon          
------------               --------         ---------          
LN-T48-PF11LLG0.cooley.com LN-T48-PF11LLG0$ 12/10/2019 14:59:17
LN-T48-PF11LLJP.cooley.com LN-T48-PF11LLJP$ 12/10/2019 04:44:39

Comment: @Khalifa96 Try again. Are you admin on all machines?

Comment: I've never logged on to these machines they belong to Users I wish to pull a list of the users and machines, My Admin rights should enable me to run queries on the physical machines.