# Get Last logged on user on a computer

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to get a list of user names of people who have logged on to the computers from a list of machines in a .txt file then export into a .csv table which displays

- The ComputerName
- The UserName (Of the last person to log on to it)
- The Last time the user logged on to the machine

My code:

```
$machines = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\name\Desktop\Winver\MachineNames.txt
Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $machines –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select Username,PSComputerName,LastLogonDate
```

Comment: Why are you asking the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322343/query-list-of-computers-output-last-logged-on-user-and-last-logon-date) again where I have already answered that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear in the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `-MaxEvents` variable to get more users:

```
$machines = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\khalifam\Desktop\Winver\MachineNames.txt)

ForEach ($machine in $machines) {

    Get-WinEvent  -Computer $machine -FilterHashtable @{Logname='Security';ID=4672} -MaxEvents 3 |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Properties[1].Value}
}
```